# How do I stop a stored procedure from using a saved execution plan?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that takes xml input, and seems to not be able to pick the right execution plan when the xml parameter is significantly different.

I would like the stored procedure to generate a new execution plan every time it executes, so I do not get bad performance when the execution plan is wrong.

What is the command I can use to make this occur?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WITH RECOMPILE` hint in your SP script.

Something like :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spname @par varchar(30) 
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    Query logic        
GO
```

**Note:** Using `RECOMPILE` at the `SP level` is going to cause the SP to be recompiled on every call, so if you know which piece inside your SP is causing the plan affinity, you could use the `RECOMPILE` hint only with that query instead of recompiling the entire SP.

[Link to MSDN DOC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx)

Comment: perfect! I knew it would be something stupid simple. i just put this in the body of the stored proc, at the beginning?

Comment: Right after your `create` statement. I have added a sample code piece

Answer (score 1):

add `WITH RECOMPILE` to your stored procedure definition.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx)